# Composition of Lipschitz function and absolutely continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Given $F(y)=\int_0^y f(s)ds$ for some integrable function $f$ and $G$ a Lipschitz function, show that $G(F(x))=\int_0^x h(t)dt$ for some integrable $h$.

I can only show that G(F(x)) is absolutely continuous, but that only implies $G(F(x))-G(F(0))=\int_0^x h(t)dt$ for some $h$. Since $G(F(0))=G(0)$, which is not necessary to be $0$, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @This is a correct edition of another question of mine.

Comment: The problem as stated is simply wrong - you need to add the assumption that $G(0)=0$ (or fix it in some other way).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Glad to hear that. Thanks!